# Spring Boot 2, LiquiGraph and 503 error with Actuator health endpoint - org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-data-neo4j, spring-boot-actuator, liquigraph

In my Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 application, I have installed LiquiGraph by using the following Maven dependencies:

```
    dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquigraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquigraph-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-bolt</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also use Spring Data Neo4j 5 and this is my Neo4j config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.neo4j")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig {

    @Value("${neo4j.bolt.server.database.uri}")
    private String boltServerDatabaseUri;

    @Value("${neo4j.jdbc.server.database.uri}")
    private String jdbcServerDatabaseUri;

    @Value("${neo4j.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${neo4j.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.example.domain.model.neo4j");
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("liquigraph")
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {

        // @formatter:off
        return new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder()
                .autoIndex("validate")
                .credentials(username, password)
                .uri(boltServerDatabaseUri)
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcServerDatabaseUri);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

}
```

Right now my Spring Boot Actuator health endpoint responds with the `503 Status code` and the following error inside JSON:

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "details": {
    "elasticsearch": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "clusterName": "elasticsearch",
        "numberOfNodes": 1,
        "numberOfDataNodes": 1,
        "activePrimaryShards": 15,
        "activeShards": 15,
        "relocatingShards": 0,
        "initializingShards": 0,
        "unassignedShards": 15
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 120031539200,
        "free": 78051127296,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    },
    "mongo": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "version": "3.4.6"
      }
    },
    "db": {
      "status": "DOWN",
      "details": {
        "database": "Neo4j",
        "error": "org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT 1]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Some errors occurred : \n[Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError]:Invalid input 'L': expected 't/T' (line 1, column 3 (offset: 2))\n\"SELECT 1\"\n   ^\n; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Some errors occurred : \n[Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError]:Invalid input 'L': expected 't/T' (line 1, column 3 (offset: 2))\n\"SELECT 1\"\n   ^\n"
      }
    },
    "neo4j": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "nodes": 194
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What may be a reason for this and how to fix it?

**UPDATED**

This is my project Maven dependencies tree:

```
com.example:api:war:0.0.1
+- com.example:domain:jar:0.0.1:compile
|  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  |  \- org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:jar:1.4.4:compile
|  +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.0.RC1:compile
|  +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.0.RC1:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.0.RC1:compile
|  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |     \- org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  |        \- io.github.lukehutch:fast-classpath-scanner:jar:2.7.4:compile
|  +- org.liquigraph:liquigraph-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.2:compile
|  |  \- org.liquigraph:liquigraph-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
|  |     \- org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc-driver:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.2:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc-bolt:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-jdbc:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.5.0:compile
|  |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.5.0:compile
|  |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.5.0:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
|  |     +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
|  |     +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:6.6.0:compile
|  |     |  +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.1:compile
|  |     |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
|  |     |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
|  |     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.9.2:compile
|  |     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.2:compile
|  |     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.9.2:compile
|  |     |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
|  |     |  \- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.4.0:compile
|  |     +- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty3-client:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:reindex-client:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     |  |  \- org.elasticsearch.client:rest:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.3:compile
|  |     |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.8:compile
|  |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     |  |  \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.3:compile
|  |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:percolator-client:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |     \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:jar:5.5.3:compile
|  |        +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
|  |        +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
|  |        +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
|  |        +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
|  |        +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
|  |        +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
|  |        \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.16.Final:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-twitter:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
|  |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.0.0.RC1:compile
|  +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.11.0.0:compile
|  |     +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.3.0:compile
|  |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2.6:compile
|  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0-rc1:compile
|  +- com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:jar:20160924.1:compile
|  +- eu.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:jar:1.20:compile
|  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.0:compile
|  |  +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:compile
|  |  +- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:compile
|  |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java6:jar:2.3.13:compile
|  \- com.novemberain:quartz-mongodb:jar:2.0.0:compile
|     +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.5.0:runtime
|     \- org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.7.0:runtime
+- com.example:coinmarketcap:jar:0.0.1:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.2:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.2:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.2:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:jar:2.9.2:compile
|  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.4.Final:compile
|  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
|  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.8.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.8.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
|  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.0.0-rc.3:compile
|     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.10:compile
|     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-facebook:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
|  +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
|  +- org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:jar:2.0.0.M4:compile
|  \- org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:jar:3.0.0.M3:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  \- org.springframework.social:spring-social-linkedin:jar:2.0.0.M3:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.8.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
|     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
+- org.springframework.social:spring-social-google:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.social:spring-social-github:jar:1.0.0.M4:compile
+- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
|  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
|  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
|  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
+- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:2.4.0:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
+- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.8:compile
|  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
+- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
|  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.10:compile
|  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
|  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
+- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.6.0:compile
+- com.github.dfabulich:sitemapgen4j:jar:1.0.6:compile
+- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:jar:2.9.0:test
|  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.5.0-beta-1:test
|  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.5.0-beta-1:test
|  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.3:test
|  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
|  +- com.jayway.restassured:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
|  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.5.0-beta-1:test
|  |  \- com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured-common:jar:2.9.0:test
|  \- com.jayway.restassured:xml-path:jar:2.9.0:test
+- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
+- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.12:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.2:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.12:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.1:compile
|  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.0.M6:compile
|  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.9.1:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.1:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.0.M6:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.M6:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.M6:test
|  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.8.0:test
|  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.11.0:test
|  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.8:test
|  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.8:test
|  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
|  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
|  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
|  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.1.RELEASE:test
|  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.0:test
+- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:2.0-EDR1:compile
|  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
|  +- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:compile
|  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
+- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
+- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.5.0:compile
|  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
|  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
|  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
+- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.14:compile
\- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
```

Comment: Could you please show all your maven dependencies here or, even better, do you have a link to this or a test project? So basically the actuator health check seems to use the wrong query but it shouldn't (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/neo4j/Neo4jHealthIndicator.java) this seems to come from (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.java)

Comment: I have updated my question with the  project Maven dependencies tree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

Add `management.health.db.enabled=false` to your config.

**Details**

Because you are also registering a JDBC DataSource in your config to work with liquigraph, the auto configuration of SpringBoot kicks in and registers an additional `HealthIndicator` for this db. You can deactivate this indicator by setting `management.health.db.enabled=false`.

Just some more information for you if you plan to upgrade to SpringBoot 2.0.0.M7: The configuration for health check has changed to:

```
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
management.health.db.enabled=false
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach works fine! I also tried to update to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 but failed because Spring Social autoconfiguration has been removed from there and I don't know right now how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative workaround, you can still get the health check for your datasource in the following way, effectively shadowing the auto-configured `DataSourceHealthIndicator` bean:

```
@Bean 
public DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator(DataSource datasource) {
    return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(datasource, "match (n) return count(n) as nodes");
}
```

Comment: You are right but the neo4j instance is already part of the health check in this case and the JDBC connection is only needed for application startup when liquigraph applies it changes.